# How to get options and values from a drop down menu using PowerShell and selenium

Tags: powershell, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the selected option from a drop down menu and use that to copy onto another form with that same drop down.

I can use
`$Motherboard = $ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="mbd"]').GetAttribute("innerText")`
to get the values in text form but I need to receive the already selected value from the drop down menu.

Would there be another get attribute to use or a different script all together?

Answer (score 0):

to get the value, you should try :

```
$Motherboard = $ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="mbd"]').GetAttribute("value")
```

print this in console and see if that helps.